# Detect environment variable change in Tcl

Tags: environment-variables, tcl

Is there any way to detect an environment variable change DURING the execution of a Tcl script (I use Tk so the execution can be long) ?
For instance, if I define an environment variable MYVAR=1, then I can access it from Tcl by writing $ENV(MYVAR). Let's say now that during the execution of the Tcl program, I switch MYVAR to 2. Is there a way, or maybe a command, that scans every environment variable again so I can get 2 when I call $ENV(MYVAR) ?

Answer (score 1):

First off, other processes will not see changes to the environment variables of any process. Children get a copy of the current environment when they are created, and that's it.

Secondly, to see a change in the environment variables, put a [`trace`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.7/TclCmd/trace.htm#M14) on the `::env` variable (but tracing an individual variable is *not* recommended). I can't remember if this works reliably between threads, but within a thread it's pretty good provided you don't have C code modifying the variables behind your back.

```
proc detectChange {name1 name2 op} {
    # We know what name1 and op are in this case; I'll ignore them
    if {$name2 eq "MYVAR"} {
        puts "MYVAR changed to $::env(MYVAR)"
    }
}
trace add variable ::env write detectChange
```

Note that Tk internally uses traces a lot (but the C API for them, not the Tcl language API for them).